# Navigate in Windows Dialog with arrow keys

Tags: windows, api, dialog, arrow-keys

I am using plain Windows API.
I would like to navigate between the Textboxes of a Dialog using arrow keys VK_UP, VK_DOWN. VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT.
I have subclassed the Textboxes in order to get the WM_CHAR, and I get every keystroke, including backspace, delete, etc but no arrow keys!
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for advice!

```
    //subclassing
SetWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_TEXTBOX1),TextBoxProc, IDC_TEXTBOX1,param);
```

with

```
LRESULT CALLBACK
TextBoxProc (HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam,
             UINT_PTR Id, DWORD_PTR param)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
       case WM_CHAR:
            char c= (char)wParam;
etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `WM_KEYDOWN` instead of `WM_CHAR`

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TextBoxProc(
    HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR, DWORD_PTR)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        if (wParam == VK_DOWN)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"VK_DOWN\n");
            return TRUE;// or break!
        }
        break;
    }
    default:break;
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting any WM_KEYDOWN. I only get WM_CHAR for keystrokes except arrow keys, Tab and Enter.

Comment: It works with above sample. `WM_CHAR` does not give you virtual keys, you need `WM_KEYDOWN`. Maybe something is happening `TranslateMessage`, please post minimum code.

Comment: Sorry! Stupid of me! Of course it is working, I get WM_KEYDOWN for arrow keys!
Thank you very much!